# How to get controller to set ObjectId from posted JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a controller that adds or edits an entity which is sent to the controller as a JSON object.

Here is the controller:

```
public JsonResult SaveOrUpdateUser(User user)
{
    Collection.Save(user);
    //Collection is MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection<User>
    return Json(user);
}
```

If user is a new user, everything works perfectly. The mongo driver sets the ID like it should, and returns the new user with their ID set. *However* if the user is an existing user, and I'm updating something, mongo thinks it's a new user because MVC doesn't seem to be able to automatically set the ObjectId from the JSON I'm sending.

The JSON for an *existing* user looks like this (edited for brevity)

```
{
    "Id": "5230d5c5eae61521585eda99",
    "Username": "someone@domain.com",
    "Password": "newpassword"
}
```

And the C# User class:

```
public class User
{
    public ObjectId Id {get; set;}
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

However, `user`, when parsed by MVC, looks like this:

```
ObjectId Id = ObjectId(000000000000000000000000);
string Username = "someone@domain.com";
string Password = "newpassword";
```

As such, as far as the mongo driver is concerned, this is a new entity. So, is there a way to control how MVC parses the JSON into a `User` so that the ObjectId is properly set if it exists?

Comment: How is an instance of `ObjectId` created?  Does it have a constructor that takes the hexadecimal string as an argument so you can create the id like `new ObjectId("5230d5c5eae61521585eda99")`?

Comment: It's `ObjectId.Parse('xxxxxx')` if you're creating one from a string. It's easy to create a new ObjectId though... my problem is that MVC doesn't seem to know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had much luck using the default Model Binder for deserializing JSON.  Try using Newtonsoft's library, I believe it is included with MVC 4 projects in Visual Studio 2012.  If not you should be able to find it in the Nuget Package Manager.

You can either create a custom Model Binder for `User` and deserialize the object there or you could make the `user` parameter to you `SaveOrUpdateUser` a `string` instead and then do the deserialization there.

In either case the code is simply:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonString)
```

Newtonsoft's JSON deserialization is pretty sophisticated and I was very impressed with how it just worked, even on deserializing some JSON into a custom object that had a Dictionary of another custom type as one of its properties.  That being said, if it is not able to figure it out with the default configuration you can help it out by creating a custom `JsonConverter`.  I have not done this myself so I will have to test out an example before I can provide guidance on that.

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching, I found out how to handle this. I wanted to avoid manually deserializing the JSON object for each request (even if I had a generic factory method), and much preferred the object to be automatically bound by the controller.

The answer is to create a custom model binder that overrides `BindModel()` in `System.Web.Mvc`. Since this is an issue for any entity I have stored in Mongo, and not just the `User` class, my custom model binder needed to be generic so that I wouldn't have to create a largely redundant model binder for each entity I have.

Here is what this class looks like:

```
public class MongoEntityDataBinder<T> : DefaultModelBinder where T: IDataEntity
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string body;
        using(var stream = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream)
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(body)) return null;

        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(body);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Next, this custom model binder needs to be registered, so in Global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MongoEntityDataBinder<IDataEntity>), new MongoEntityDataBinder<IDataEntity>());
```

And finally, my controller now looks like this:

```
public JsonResult SaveOrEditUser([ModelBinder(typeof(MongoEntityDataBinder<User>))] User user)
{
    //Function body
}
```

One final thing to note is that Json.NET doesn't inherently know how to serialize/deserialize ObjectId either, so I also needed to override `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter.WriteJson()` and `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter.ReadJson()` and then apply `[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]` to the Id property in `IDataEntity`

This article was an excellent starting point: [ASP.NET Custom Model Binder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder)

Comment: Glad the Newtonsoft library worked out for you as well as the custom model binder that I suggested.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know what MVC called the process of converting JSON to a model (object binding) so your answer gave me a great starting point for what to search for.